# How to map different types of geometries on a single variable using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made this graph using ggplot2:

[image]

I'd like to have the "Interés Real" time series as a `geom_bar()` instead of a line. I tried to plot each of my series sepparately, using the following code:

```
ggOjb=ggplot(base)+geom_line(aes(x=periodo,y=tasa))+
  geom_line(aes(x=periodo,y=inflacion))+
  geom_bar(aes(x=periodo,y=real2),stat="identity",alpha=.7)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=2,size=1)
```

And I got this:

[image]

Which is pretty much what I wanted. But I would also like to keep the guides. Thus I want to know how can I map a variable to the type of geometry.

Thank you in advance! I hope I was clear.

Comment: Some example data would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by 'keep the guides'?

Comment: Add `geom_line(aes(x=periodo,y=real2))` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reshape your data from wide to long and then use different dataframes in each geom.

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Time = 1:25, A = rnorm(25), B = rnorm(25), C = rnorm(25)*1.5)

df %>% 
  gather("Series", "Value", - Time) -> df

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = df %>% filter(Series == "C"),  aes(x=Time, y=Value, fill = "SeriesA"), stat="identity") +
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(Series == "A"), aes(x=Time, y=Value, col = "SeriesB")) +
  geom_line(data = df %>% filter(Series == "B"), aes(x=Time, y=Value, col = "SeriesC")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0,linetype=2,size=1) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Series A and B", values = c("SeriesB" = "blue", "SeriesC" = "green")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Series C", values = c("SeriesA" = "grey"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I originaly had it in a long format, but didn't know I could filter inside the ggplot functions.